# Why is my child component not updating when I change its state from the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
Board {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [[{value: 12, price: 14}, {...}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}]],
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    let newArray = [...this.state.array];
    newArray[0][0].value = 14;
    this.setState({array: newArray});
  }

  render() {
    return <Square
             value={this.state.array[0][0].value}
             onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
           />
  }
}

function Square(props) {
  return <div className="square">{props.value}</div>;
}
```

In the parent, I would change the state of the array with this.setState(array: newUpdatedArray) but the child component will not update even if the array state is not the same anymore. I'm new to React so I'm not quite sure when child component actually updates... after clicking on the square, the value displayed remains 12.

What I have noticed is if the child component took the whole array instead of a value, and we recovered the value from the child component, the child component would then update, but I don't want to store whole arrays in every child component.

Comment: can you post a proper code syntax instead? the problem might be in your syntax

Comment: In your code, there is both **class component** and **function component**. You should choose one or the other. I would recommend choosing functional components.

Comment: @nico263nico this is not true. It's possible to use both class and functional components.
IamL your child is not updating probably because your props.value is not mutating as is a nested array and you are using a spread operator on the first level. Try with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) to copy the old state

Comment: @FrancescoClementi I didn't say it's not possible. I said it should not be done

Comment: @nico263nico why not ? does it say that in the official docs ? It's perfectly ok to use both depending on what your component does.

Comment: @MihaiT For multiple reasons actually. The readability of your code, the possible undocumented behaviors, the community packages that are more and more done with and for functional components. We can create a chatroom if anyone wants to discuss it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it looks like what someone else mentioned before. Your data is nested array/objects. When you spread it, it only creates a shallow copy. You need to use a function to create a deep copy. You can use a library like lodash for that. Or you can create your own like this:

```
const deepCopy = (input) => {
  if (
    typeof input === 'number' ||
    typeof input === 'string' ||
    typeof input === 'boolean'
  )
    return input;
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    const newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      newArr.push(deepCopy(input[i]));
    }
    return newArr;
  } else {
    const newObj = {};
    for (let key in input) {
      if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newObj[key] = deepCopy(input[key]);
      }
    }
    return newObj;
  }
};
```

Then you can have your handleClick like this:

```
handleClick() {
  let newArray = deepCopy(this.state.array);
  newArray[0][0].value = 14;
  this.setState({array: newArray});
}
```